# Why is MCVE so utterly beautiful? If yes, can we put it more places, or make it more bright and garish and attention seeky?

Tags: feature-request, minimal-reproducible-example

I recently came across a comment including:

[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

And I realised I have never come across it before, which seems odd given the amount of time I've been posting on Stack Exchange and generally making a nuisance of myself. If it had been diplomatically introduced to me when I first started... I... um... would probably have found it patronising and ignored it but... Probably if I weren't so hot headed I'd have found the article really useful and it would have saved a lot of "huh, why was this question downvoted" confusion, which I like to save for genuinely politically motivated downvotes and conspiracies.

In any eventuality, I assume the link to it is tucked away somewhere in the help center, so I just thought I'd ask if we could put it somewhere more prominent, or if I'm just being a massive buffoon and overlooking some already obvious placement... Or maybe people could just post it in comments to more questions, as and where it's relevant. I shall certain try to.

It really is rather lovely.

Comment: _"Or maybe people could just post it as comment to more questions, as and where it's relevant. "_ It appears as relevant when the question is closed for the appropriate reasons. Also it's very frequently used in comments, and there's a magic short cut for it `[MCVE]`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I guess mine have never been closed for those reasons then? Or I didn't notice it, which seems likely also. I'm sure a lot of the time I could have benefited from it, and I lament not finding it sooner.

Comment: Maybe an idea would be to add a link to it on the [asking advice page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice), which all new users see when attempting to ask a question.

Comment: @JonasCz Hmm, it's already well present in the 1st link listed: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think a direct link to [mcve] _on that asking advice page_ would be even better, or am I missing something and there is one already ?

Comment: @JonasCz You're probably right. It's an indirect link there yes.

Comment: [The tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) does a good job of explaining how the network works, but not what is expected by users. You can visit the help center at the end of the tour and then somewhere find [ask] and [mcve], but it is pretty far-fetched for such *utterly beautiful* information. A good improvement of the tour page would make new users understand Stack Overflow (and the other sections of the network) a lot better, and make it easier for others to tell them where to go to learn in case they missed it by simply writing `[tour]`.

Comment: Relevant... there's also [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @Grenarme I would have upvoted you an extra time if I could, just because you appear to be subtly making fun of the *utterly beautiful* part of my question, which is definitely merited.

Comment: I can't bring my self to call it "beautiful" until the leading "e" in "example" gets capitalized.  The copy editor in me screams whenever I type `[MCVE]` and get an "MCVe" instead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks also for indirectly pointing me to the list of `[magic]` shorthands; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000

Comment: The best thing about MCVE is that when you try to create a MCVE, you generally solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is there a list of such shortcuts?

Comment: @GolezTrol 2 comments up. Check tripleee's link.

Comment: The last five to ten times I started asking an SO question, I solved the problem during the course of creating the MCVE.

Comment: You missed [Usenet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet) (before it was [destroyed by AOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September)).

Comment: @RobotKarel314, I'm mentally downvoting your comment for not knowing that it's not possible to downvote comments :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ As for the [MCVE] magic shortcut - it's awesome. Where can I find the list of all such *magic shortcuts*?

Comment: @fracz Read all of the comments above thoroughly.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The link has been there for a long time in the Asking section. It is also a magical link. Adding `[mcve]` to a comment will automatically add a link to that help page, as suggested [in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325513/why-is-mcve-so-utterly-beautiful-if-yes-can-we-put-it-more-places-or-make-it/325530?noredirect=1#comment353948_325530) by [NathanOliver](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver). (also note you will need to add in more characters to fulfill the minimum required for a comment e.g. "please see [mcve]")

There is so much to remember on this site I keep the important things in one of the following forms.I would suggest:

1. Bookmarking it.
2. You can also make [a gist of auto-comments](https://gist.github.com/yvettec/e8c1fb032bec023f816c) and keep the link in those, so it's available for comments.
3. I also keep the links on my profile that I want to keep handy:
4. I also keep a text file of auto comments to paste, update and save when I visit a site.
5. Also, as pointed out in the [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325513/why-is-mcve-so-utterly-beautiful-if-yes-can-we-put-it-more-places-or-make-it/325530?noredirect=1#comment353708_325530) by [Elliott Frisch](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch) there is the [Repository of useful pro-forma comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments)
6. There is also [common_comments_box.user.js](https://gist.github.com/kms70847/b600792c78b0790c3c4d) written by [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/953482/kevin) that can be used with Grease Monkey as suggested [byPM 2Ring](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4014959/pm-2ring) in [the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325513/why-is-mcve-so-utterly-beautiful-if-yes-can-we-put-it-more-places-or-make-it/325530?noredirect=1#comment353790_325530).
7. There is also [Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments) written by [Benjol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11410/benjol) (can be used with Grease Monkey, or as an extension, depending on browser/version).

Comment: Yeah, I can see it now... I just couldn't see it so well when I started out. Right now I have one contact lense in, so it's a little blurry, but that's besides the point ;).